# What is the web dependency in the Kotlin Spring Boot tutorial?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

In the Kotlin [Spring Boot tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/) it asks you to include the web dependency, like this:

[image]

but in the actual [Spring Boot initializr](https://start.spring.io/#!language=kotlin&type=gradle-project), I don't see that:

[image]

What's the web dependency that's required? Is it Spring Web Starter? Is this tutorial out of date and/or obsolete?

Comment: A starter is always a good choice. You should go with `web starter`. `Reactive web` is fancy but I'd advise against it if you're only trying to work through the tutorial. Not using a starter is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`spring web starter` is the one you need to select it's what they refer to in the tutorial.

its the full name for it.

if you look in the tutorial they later show the `pom.xml` There you can see that they have declared the:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and the tuturial still seems okey so go for it.